# Show 0 when there is no rows in .agg.count()

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, conditional-statements

I have some data that I am aggregating like this:

```
count = (
    t1
    .where(sf.col('status') == 'i')
    .select('name',
            'id',
            'prod',
            'date')
    .groupby('name',
            'id',
            'date'
    .agg(
        sf.count('prod').alias('count')
    )
```

This works fine but I would also like to see the `count` = 0 for rows where the `account` does not have rows with `status = i`. Is there a way in which I can conditionally aggregate, something similar to this?

```
count = (
    t1
    .select('name',
            'id',
            'prod',
            'status',
            'date')
    .groupby('name',
            'id',
            'date'
    .agg(
        if no rows with status = i, 0
        else sf.count('prod').alias('count')
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try doing a conditional count with a `when` statement:

```
count = (
    t1
    .select('name',
            'id',
            'prod',
            'date',
            'status')
    .groupby('name',
            'id',
            'date'
    .agg(
        sf.count(
            sf.when(sf.col('status') == 'i', sf.col('prod'))
        ).alias('count')
    )
)
```

But the below code may give a different result, if each group can contain different statuses:

```
count = (
    t1
    .select('name',
            'id',
            'prod',
            'date',
            'status')
    .groupby('name',
            'id',
            'date'
    .agg(
        sf.when(~sf.max(sf.col('status') == 'i'), 0)
          .otherwise(sf.count('prod'))
          .alias('count')
    )
)
```

Comment: The first solution works good but I don't understand why. The count condition is a count of prod when status = i. This seems similar to my original Q but with the filter to `i` being inside the aggregation instead of before but your solution shows rows with 0 and mine doesn't

Comment: When you filter away the rows with `status = i`, the groups with `count = 0` disappeared before you do the grouping, so you cannot see those groups after grouping. With the first code here, those groups are present before the grouping, and returns a count of 0 after grouping.